# How to select all documents where one date field is after another date field in FaunaDB

Tags: faunadb

I have a very simple collection with documents that look like this:

```
{
  ...
  latestEdit: Time(...),
  lastPublished: Time(...)
}
```

I would like to query all documents that have a `latestEdit` time that's after `lastPublished` time.

I find FQL to be very different to SQL and I'm finding the transition quite hard.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fauna's FQL is not declarative, so you have to construct the appropriate indexes and queries to help you solve problems like this.

Fauna indexes have a feature called "bindings", which allow you to provide a user-defined function that can compute a value based on document values. The binding lets us index the computed value by itself (rather than having to index on `latestEdit` or `lastPublished`). Here's what that might look like:

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "edit_after_published",
  source: {
    collection: Collection("test"),
    fields: {
      needsPublish: Query(
        Lambda(
          "doc",
          Let(
            {
              latestEdit: Select(["data", "latestEdit"], Var("doc")),
              lastPublished: Select(["data", "lastPublished"], Var("doc")),
            },
            If(
              GT(Var("latestEdit"), Var("lastPublished")),
              true,
              false
            )
          )
        )
      )
    }
  },
  terms: [ { binding: "needsPublish" } ]
})
```

You can see that we define a binding called `needsPublish`. The binding uses `Let` to define named values for the two document fields that we want to compare, and then the `If` statement checks to see if the `latestEdit` value is greather than `lastPublished` value: when it is we return `true`, otherwise we return `false`. Then, the binding is used in the index's `terms` definition, which defines the fields that we want to be able to search on.

I created sample documents in a collection called `test`, like so:

```
> Create(Collection("test"), { data: { name: "first", latestEdit: Now(), lastPublished: TimeSubtract(Now(), 1, "day") }})
{
  ref: Ref(Collection("test"), "306026106743423488"),
  ts: 1628108088190000,
  data: {
    name: 'first',
    latestEdit: Time("2021-08-04T20:14:48.121Z"),
    lastPublished: Time("2021-08-03T20:14:48.121Z")
  }
}
> Create(Collection("test"), { data: { name: "second", lastPublished: Now(), latestEdit: TimeSubtract(Now(), 1, "day") }})
{
  ref: Ref(Collection("test"), "306026150784664064"),
  ts: 1628108130150000,
  data: {
    name: 'second',
    lastPublished: Time("2021-08-04T20:15:30.148Z"),
    latestEdit: Time("2021-08-03T20:15:30.148Z")
  }
}
```

The first document subtracts one day from `lastPublished` and the second document subtracts one day from `latestEdit`, to test both conditions of the binding.

Then we can query for all documents where `needsPublish` results in `true`:

```
> Map(Paginate(Match(Index("edit_after_published"), true)), Lambda("X", Get(Var("X"))))
{
  data: [
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("test"), "306026106743423488"),
      ts: 1628108088190000,
      data: {
        name: 'first',
        latestEdit: Time("2021-08-04T20:14:48.121Z"),
        lastPublished: Time("2021-08-03T20:14:48.121Z")
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And we can also query for all documents where `needsPublish` is `false`:

```
> Map(Paginate(Match(Index("edit_after_published"), false)), Lambda("X", Get(Var("X"))))
{
  data: [
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("test"), "306026150784664064"),
      ts: 1628108130150000,
      data: {
        name: 'second',
        lastPublished: Time("2021-08-04T20:15:30.148Z"),
        latestEdit: Time("2021-08-03T20:15:30.148Z")
      }
    }
  ]
}
```